# On finding an explicit form of a particular recurrence relation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

Let $f$ be integrable over the interval $[0, 1]$, and

$$I_n = \int_0^{1} x^n f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Suppose $f(x) = f(1-x)$; we can then show that

$$I_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k \, I_{k}, $$

by letting $u = 1-x$ and using the binomial theorem.

My question is if we can extract an explicit form for $I_n$ from this recurrence relation. I don't mind if some of the constants involved (in particular, say $I_0$, $I_1$, $I_2$, etc.) are part of the explicit form, and I actually do expect those constants to pop up somewhere (not entirely sure how exactly, but that's my gut instinct).

If not, then is there any existing literature that you would recommend me to look up that involve problems like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://gs1.dlut.edu.cn/newVersion/Files/dsxx/1161.pdf) could help?

Comment: Thank you. As a consequence in that paper, $I_0, I_2, ... , I_{2n}$ are linearly independent in the space containing all $I_n$ , and thus can form a basis. That's pretty interesting how all of that unraveled in this.